# Множественные каскадные циклы EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Такой вопрос, столкнулся с исключением, связанным с появлением множественных каскадных циклов когда проектировал свою БД. Нашел много инфы по этому поводу, но так совсем и не понял, именно когда у меня появляется данное исключение? Когда при удалении сущности удаляются две другие, где одна из них так же зависит от второй или как?

Comment: В принципе верно поняли. / Только это не относится напрямую к Entity Framework. Это скорее относится к SQL, к проектированию БД.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не подскажите, как правильнее может в этом случае поступать? Или это все зависит больше от ситуации?

Comment: Вероятно, стоит задать отдельный вопрос с меткой `sql`, без упоминания C# и EF. Тогда могут откликнуться спецы по БД и объяснить (но могут и не откликнуться). И крайне желателен пример/схема создаваемой БД - без этого вопрос могут закрыть.

Comment: Ну а так, да, - всё зависит от ситуации. | В EF всё осложняется тем, что каскадное удаление может происходить как в самой БД (на сервере), так и в клиентском коде. [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete)